# use enum in std::atomic::compare_exchange_strong()

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, stdatomic

I tried to use std::atomic::compare_exchange_strong() with enum but it raise this error

```
cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘std::__atomic_base<int>::__int_type&’ {aka ‘int&’} to an rvalue of type ‘std::__atomic_base<int>::__int_type’ {aka ‘int’}
```

here is part of my code, simplified for the key.

```
enum LockStatus
{
    readed, 
    reading,
    writing,
    written
};

int main()
{
    atomic_int **lock;
    lock=new atomic_int* [n];
    for(int i=0; i<n ;i++)
    {
        if(lock[i]->compare_exchange_strong(readed,writing))
        {
           //something to do 
        }
    }
}
```

I think this problem is caused by `enum` is a right value but `compare_exchange_strong` need a left value, if I define these `LockStatus` as int it will work,but I was wondering if there is a more elegant why to solve this problem?

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: first param needs to be a variable with type of your enum

Comment: It won't work with `int` either; something like `lock[i]->compare_exchange_strong(0, 2)` still won't compile. Enum is a red herring. The first parameter of `compare_exchange_strong` is an lvalue reference; you need to declare a variable, assign to it the value you expect the atomic to have, and after the call the variable will be updated with the value the atomic actually had.

Comment: If it was just a spinlock (not a readers/writers lock), you could unconditionally `exchange` like `if (unlocked == lock[i].exchange(locked))`, so it's now locked, and you find out whether you locked it or whether someone else already had it locked.